# How to solve the issue of Nexus not finding artifacts from added repository for the exist-db database?

Tags: java, maven, nexus, exist-db

When I add dependency for the eXist-db artifacts inside my pom.xml for my project as explained on [the official place for eXist artifacts](https://github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo) everything works as expected. Here are the fragments added to the pom:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.exist-db</groupId>
  <artifactId>exist-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
<repository>
  <id>exist</id>
  <url>https://raw.github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/master/</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
```

But than, when I want to use Nexus (nexus-2.14.4-03) for importing dependencies, I have trouble to make it work. In my project's pom.xml I have erased repositories element to make it work through the Nexus repository.

In Nexus I have added new proxy repository for the eXist-db artifacts. Than I have added that repository to the Public Repositories group. Also, inside maven's settings.xml I have added mirror code like this:

```
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    <name>Nexus Repository.</name>
</mirror>
```

Nexus repository seems to work. I can browse it from the Nexus, see it as global repository from the Eclipse, and inspect it in the browser with list of artifacts in it, except the eXist-db.

Back to the question. In my proxy repository settings for eXist-db inside Nexus, when I put https://raw.github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/master/ as the Remote Storage Location, I have `Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable` message. Btw that link is redirected to the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/master/ And from the wrapper.log file of Nexus I have this line:

```
admin org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository - Remote peer of proxy repository "exist-db" [id=exist-db] threw a org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.RemoteStorageException exception. Connection/transport problems occured while connecting to remote peer of the repository. Auto-blocking this repository to prevent further connection-leaks and known-to-fail outbound connections until administrator fixes the problems, or Nexus detects remote repository as healthy. - Cause(s): Unexpected response code while executing GET method [repositoryId="exist-db", requestPath="/", remoteUrl="https://raw.github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/master/"]. Expected: "SUCCESS (200)". Received: 400 : Bad Request
```

So, when I try to put this repo URL inside the web browser I am getting: `400: Invalid request` as expected.

I guessed that is not the right link for the proxy repository in Nexus, because Nexus needs the list of artifacts on that link. So, I have changed it to the `https://github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo` and the `Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable` message disappeared. These are the lines from the log:

```
INFO  [proxy-3-thread-24] admin org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.storage.remote.httpclient.HttpClientRemoteStorage - Updating remote transport for proxy repository "exist-db" [id=exist-db]...
WARN  [proxy-3-thread-24] admin org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.maven2.M2Repository - Remote peer of proxy repository "exist-db" [id=exist-db] detected as healthy, un-blocking the proxy repository (it was AutoBlocked by Nexus).
INFO  [qtp16973920-132] admin org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration - Applying Nexus Configuration due to changes in [Public Repositories] made by admin...
INFO  [ar-4-thread-1] admin org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.maven.routing.internal.ManagerImpl - Unpublished prefix file of "Public Repositories" [id=public] (and is marked for noscrape)
ERROR [qtp16973920-49] admin org.sonatype.nexus.rest.NexusRestletResource - java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -10
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:935)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:76) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.rrb.parsers.HtmlRemoteRepositoryParser.getLinkUrl(HtmlRemoteRepositoryParser.java:173) ~[na:na]
...
```

Than I tried to update repository index from inside the Nexus, and these are the log lines from that action:

```
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.tasks.UpdateIndexTask - Scheduled task (UpdateIndexTask) started :: Updating repository index "exist-db" from path / and below.
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager - Trying to get remote index for repository "exist-db" [id=exist-db]
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager - Cannot fetch remote index for repository "exist-db" [id=exist-db] as it does not publish indexes.
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.NexusScanningListener - Scanning of repositoryID="exist-db" started.
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.NexusScanningListener - Scanning of repositoryID="exist-db" finished: scanned=0, added=0, updated=0, removed=0, scanningDuration=0:00:00.328
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.DefaultIndexerManager - Publishing index for repository exist-db
INFO  [pxpool-1-thread-6] admin org.sonatype.nexus.index.tasks.UpdateIndexTask - Scheduled task (UpdateIndexTask) finished :: Updating repository index "exist-db" from path / and below. (started 2017-06-29T15:53:28+02:00, runtime 0:00:01.375)
```

At the end, in Nexus under Routing tab for my exist-db proxy repository I have:

```
Publishing:
Status: Not published.
Message: Discovery in progress or unable to discover remote content (see discovery status).

Discovery:
Status: Unsuccessful.
Message: No scraper was able to scrape remote (or remote prevents scraping).
```

And I got the error message in Eclipse on project's pom.xml stating:

```
Missing artifact org.exist-db:exist-core:jar:3.2.0
```

Could someone tell me please what I am missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks like its broken see wontfix issue here: https://github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/issues/4 try create a site workaround suggested with https://github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo as url like: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_creating_a_site_repository.html

Comment: @Revive Thanks for this usefull info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw GitHub repo unfortunately only works with the `mvn` command line tool. It won't work as a source for a Nexus repo proxy.

> However, my company maintain a public Nexus repo which contains the
>   latest eXist artifacts here:
>   http://repo.evolvedbinary.com/content/repositories/exist-db/

Whilst the above URL is still valid, we have now updated to Nexus 3, which prefers a newer URL style The repository should now be accessed from: http://repo.evolvedbinary.com/repository/exist-db/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. But that repo is not so public. I've got "Access Denied : Please login before attempting further requests." message when I try to access it through browser and "Remote Automatically Blocked and Unavailable" message from the Nexus.

Comment: Apologies, that was just a misconfiguration blip here. We have now fixed that and the repo is public again now.

Comment: Thank you for investing your time to solve this issue.

Comment: I have an issue with this new repo which is exposed through the Nexus, but in attempt to solve it I removed Nexus as the repository and relied on the sole exist repository specifying it in projects pom: `<repository><id>exist</id><url>http://repo.evolvedbinary.com/content/repositories/exist-db/</url></repository>` And I got an error:
`Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.exist-db.thirdparty.se.softhouse:jargo:jar:0.4.2-SNAPSHOT-7fa1d04` That artifact is not downloaded. When repository link is replaced with `https://raw.github.com/eXist-db/mvn-repo/master/`all is working.

Comment: The artifact does seem to be there - http://repo.evolvedbinary.com/content/repositories/exist-db/org/exist-db/thirdparty/se/softhouse/jargo/0.4.2-SNAPSHOT-7fa1d04/

Perhaps you need to run `mvn -U clean install` on your project?

Comment: Because of limited space for comment I was not to precise and clear enough about the error: `.... Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.exist-db.thirdparty.se.softhouse:jargo-parent:pom:0.4.2-SNAPSHOT-7fa1d04` What is missing is [jargo-parent artifact](http://repo.evolvedbinary.com/content/repositories/exist-db/org/exist-db/thirdparty/se/softhouse/jargo-parent/) and only in repo.evolvedbinary.com‌​ repository - at least for me.

Comment: Apologies, that was indeed missing. It is now present. Should all work, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for solving this. Everything is perfect now. I have another, this time off topic question, and I would really appreciate your answer. What is the best place for asking questions regarding development of java applications with exist and its api? Here or on the exist mailing list?

Comment: The mailing list is probably more responsive and better for discussions